# Can you selectively load fixtures in symfony2

Tags: symfony, fixtures

When I run

```
console doctrine:fixtures:load --fixtures=src/App/PeopleBundle/DataFixtures/ORM
```

I don't want doctrine to purge every table that has an entity. Instead, I only want to purge tables for the fixtures that are in the explicitly specified directory.

However, it seems that, regardless of the target directory, symfony is finding every entity in every bundle, and purging every table associated with each entity.

How can I direct symfony2 to ignore all tables except for the specific tables for which I have written fixtures?

Comment: Although an old question, my answer seems to be a much nicer way of going about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you think is Doctrine supposed to figured out what to purge and what not to? There is no information in a fixture telling which entities it will be loading. If you really need this, you'll have to do it manually.

First, you could use the `--append` option to avoid purging the database. Second, the first thing you could do in your fixtures is to truncate the related tables.

Comment: Well, it could compare the data being input and the data that already exists.. that's a possibility..

Comment: No idea what you're on about there but... great!

Answer (score 4):

It's really not that hard to go about this the right way. First and foremost, yes, you use `--append`, but you'll have a load of extra things added that you don't want. So you need to perform some basic checks in your fixtures to see if you actually need to add them (if they're already in the database, you don't).

The example I'm going to show you is a simple one: I have a `locators` table containing the columns: `id` and `name`.

```
namespace Application\Model\Fixtures;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface,
    Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface,
    Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager,
    Application\Model\Entity\Locator;

/**
 * Class LoadLocators
 *
 * Pre-populates the locators table
 *
 * @package Application\Model\Fixtures
 */
class LoadLocators implements FixtureInterface, OrderedFixtureInterface
{
    /**
     * @var array The locators names that will be inserted in the database table
     */
    protected $locators = ['id', 'xpath', 'css'];

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        foreach ($this->locators as $locatorName)
        {
            $locator = $this->findOrCreateLocator($locatorName, $manager);

            /** Check if the object is managed (so already exists in the database) **/
            if (!$manager->contains($locator))
            {
                $manager->persist($locator);
            }
        }

        $manager->flush();
    }

    /**
     * Helper method to return an already existing Locator from the database, else create and return a new one
     *
     * @param string        $name
     * @param ObjectManager $manager
     *
     * @return Locator
     */
    protected function findOrCreateLocator($name, ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        return $manager->getRepository('Application\Model\Entity\Locator')->findOneBy(['name' => $name]) ?: new Locator($name);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getOrder()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

The simple change here is that, if the object already exists in the database, find it and use that one instead. It really is that simple.

The command I now run has `--append` at the end, but it doesn't append if the data already exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can load selected Fixtures by using the `--fixtures`option.

Together with `--append` you might be abled to control what you want to do, cause purging affects as said by Elnur to every Table managed by the entity manager.

Comment: The --fixtures options does not exist any more since 3.x version. For now it is no more possible to specify the fixture to load. See https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle/issues/219#issuecomment-352337579